# How can I get JAMon metrics in JConsole (via JMX)

Tags: matrix, jmx, jconsole, jamon

As per [this](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/jmx_jamon.html) document we should be able to view JAmon metrics in JConsole. However I just can't find anything about JAmon in my JConsole session:

[image]

The session is connected to a local Catalina (tomcat 7) instance running an application with JAMon dependencies (`jamon-2.80.jar`). I have the following code in the application:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String orderList(String q, int page, ModelMap modelMap) {
    Monitor monitor = MonitorFactory.start(MON_ORDER_LIST);
    try {
        List<Order> orderList = Order.find(q, PAGE_SIZE, page * PAGE_SIZE);
        modelMap.put("orderList", orderList);
    } finally {
        monitor.stop();
    }
    return jsonTemplate("order_list");
}
```

And I start the tomcat instance using Intellij.

Comment: I've tested jamon on both windows and ubuntu with java 8. No JAMon monitors are displayed by jConsole. Manually creating a custom jmx monitor works fine for a simple console app.

Answer (score 2):

In order to view JMX informations you must explicitly call

```
JmxUtils.registerMbeans();
```

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you!